# Preserve X509 client cert data from apache2 reverse proxy to jetty

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2, jetty, x509

I am not able to receive on jetty-9.3.14 the X509 client cert data which are submitted to apache2 and forwarded via `ProxyPass` directive.

```
<Location /X509>
    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 5
    SSLOptions -StdEnvVars +ExportCertData
# most of the followings are useless 
    RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_S_DN "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}s"
    RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_I_DN "%{SSL_CLIENT_I_DN}s"
    RequestHeader set SSL_SERVER_S_DN_OU "%{SSL_SERVER_S_DN_OU}s"
    RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY "%{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY}s"
    RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_V_START "%{SSL_CLIENT_V_START}s"
    RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_V_END "%{SSL_CLIENT_V_END}s"
    RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_M_VERSION "%{SSL_CLIENT_M_VERSION}s"
    RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL "%{SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL}s"
    RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_CERT "%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s"
    RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY "%{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY}s"
    RequestHeader set SSL_SERVER_M_VERSION "%{SSL_SERVER_M_VERSION}s"
    RequestHeader set SSL_SERVER_I_DN "%{SSL_SERVER_I_DN}s"
    RequestHeader set SSL_SERVER_CERT "%{SSL_SERVER_CERT}s"
</Location>
```

The above location on apache2 is effective in requiring X509 client cert to user, but these information are not forwarded to jetty.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not doable. As Jetty-9.3 does not support `mod_ajp`, apache2 needs to proxy request on `proxy_http`, that is, of course, a `http` channel.

X509 user cert data is "peeled off" when passing from https from http.

That's all.

The maximum you can do is to turn the `SSLContext` data into HTTP headers and then trust the headers with some custom logic.